# JSON nested object access

Tags: angularjs, json, angular

I am getting object from the front-end made in angular to node and want to access each object(`fname`,`lame`,..)

```
{ body:
   { some:
      { fname: 'Fuser',
        lname: 'Luser',
        userName: 'userDEMO',
        password: 'password@123',
        cPassword: 'password@123',
        currentEmail: 'some@demo.com' } } }
```

> **body.some.fname** .. others is not working here

Can any one enlignten me how to actually use these nested object in json

**If question repeated forward the link** because all the solution given are not implementing and giving `undefined` output

**---- I got the answer ----**
    req.body.body.some.fname

Comment: could you make a plunkr or fiddle

Comment: sorry I was in hurry I get access to the answer using `req.body.body.some.fname` how foolish I could be. Thank u for the time :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was in hurry for the task that i didn't realised.I used `req.body.body.some.fname`

It wad the req body. I was foolish sorry

Comment: Never-mind you can delete your question as it was specific to you and  your mistake.

Comment: @micronyks it says cannot delete as others have invested there time and efforts in question

Answer (score 1):

```
req.body.some.fname
```

or

```
response.data.body.some.fname
```

Answer (score 0):

This does not look like valid JSON, as the keys (which I assume are meant to be strings) are not placed within double quotes.

```
a = { "body":
   { "some":
      { "fname": 'Fuser',
        "lname": 'Luser',
        "userName": 'userDEMO',
        "password": 'password@123',
        "cPassword": 'password@123',
        "currentEmail": 'some@demo.com' } } }

a.body.some.fname 
// => "Fuser"


a["body"]["some"]["fname"] 
// => "Fuser"
```